# Using () => vs this.something in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to comprehend when do we use something like in jsx of our react

1. `something = {this._onRefresh}`
2. `something = {() => this._onRefresh}`
3. `something = {this._onRefresh()}`

Where `something` could be something we are passing to our

1. child component
2. `onChange` Event
3. `onClick` event
4. Any other situation you can think about

Where our `._onRefresh()` could be

```
._onRefresh = () => {
  //changes state of our react component 
  //Call redux action
  //call other functions
}
```

or In case of forms, it takes in event which triggered it

```
  ._onRefresh = (event) => {
      //takes target value to search inside the data 
      //Store data in the backend
    }
```

Can someone please explain me when do we need to use which one? will help me a lot in clearing my fundamentals of react and javascript

Comment: @Quentin although the `this` is included in his question, I think he is asking something more than just how `this` works

Comment: The question was dupe-hammered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work is a related question but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The answer depends on what `onRefresh` is expected to be equal to.

Comment: @estus Updated the question

Comment: Given that `_onRefresh` is an instance property (and an arrow function) the only option that would work is (1). (2) - you never call  the function. (3) you call the function immediatelly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points 1/2 and 3 are actually totally different.

Your point 3 executes a function and assigns the returning value to the `something`.

Your examples 1/2 assign a function to `something`

The case 3 could be used when for example you have the `disable` attribute, and you want to assign the returning `true/false` of a function.

The points 1 and 2 are assigning a function to the attribute, like for example with `onClick` attribute, which accepts a callback to be called on click.

The difference between the first and the second point is that if you put that code inside the `render` method, the second point creates a function for every render, which is not the best for performances.

Using the first point, you should pay attention on how you define the method for the reference of `this` inside the method.

If you define the class method as:

```
myMethod() {
  console.log(this); // it will be undefined by default
}
```

Then you need to bind the `this` inside the constructor if you want to access `this` inside the method:

```
this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
```

If you define the method as arrow function, it will keep the value of the `this` inside the method, so no need of the bind:

```
myMethod = () => {
  console.log(this);
};
```

Comment: Not to say that 2 is likely wrong because `_onRefresh` is only accessed w/o being called :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko :D I was assuming that his question was actually the difference in React between having an attribute assigned to a function vs an arrow function which calls the function vs a function call

Answer (score 1):

1- you are passing a function as a property to this component

2- you are creating a new function and passing it as a property to this component

3- you are passing the result (output) of calling `_onRefresh` as a property to this component

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** is valid if `_onRefresh` is actual callback function that should be passed via a prop:

```
_onRefresh = () => console.log('refresh');

...

<Component onRefresh={this._onRefresh}/>
```

Where `Component` uses `onRefresh` like:

```
// do refresh
props.onRefresh();
```

**Option 2** is valid if `_onRefresh` is actual callback function, and `onRefresh` prop is expected to be *higher-order function* by a component that accepts a callback:

```
_onRefresh = () => () => console.log('refresh');

...

<Component onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh}/>
```

Where `Component` handles `onRefresh` like:

```
// do refresh
const refreshFn = props.onRefresh();
refreshFn();
```

**Option 3** is valid if `_onRefresh` is *higher-order function* that returns another function, and this is expected by a component that accepts a callback:

```
_onRefresh = () => () => console.log('refresh');

...

<Component onRefresh={this._onRefresh()}/>
```

Where `Component` handles `onRefresh` like:

```
// do refresh
const refreshFn = props.onRefresh();
refreshFn();
```

Scenarios in options 2 and 3 are much less probable because they don't have much uses in this particular case in React.

In this case option 1 is likely correct because `_onRefresh` does not return another function and is not expected by child component. Option 2 is a mistake that will result in `_onRefresh` being never called. Option 3 is a mistake that will result in `_onRefresh` being called instantly and `undefined is not a function` error later or, even worse, erroneous behaviour with no error.